# Taught Modules meaning

Tags: terminology

I have a question about the term taught modules.What does it mean?I have found it in an academic site of university and especially school of physics and astronomy.

Can we say module tutor assistant professor Earl smith or it is more common module tutor Earl Smith assistant professor?

Answer (score 3):

In UK, the word ‘modules’, refer to what we may know as courses, units, or classes.

> [Taught module](http://socialsciences.exeter.ac.uk/students/collegehandbook_pgt/taughtmodulesanddissertations/) is led by one or more module tutors, who are
>   responsible for the teaching of the module and with whom you work on a
>   day-to-day basis.

Any questions that you have regarding a particular module, or your work within it, should be directed to the relevant tutor.

> Modules are of either one or two semesters in length.

All modules require written work. All the required coursework normally needs to be completed before the end of the term in which the module is taught and submitted within the given deadlines.

Comment: I've also seen this term in the US for subunits of a course, particularly when there's some sort of logical separation (e.g. my driver's ed course had ~10 modules, each of which could be taken separately but which were all part of the one course).